# how to correctly add jquery in activeadmin with api only mode and no application.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

When trying to make a custom page in active_admin in a rails api-only app, I get the following:

```
$ is not defined
```

I moved `jquery.js` into my `/assets` folder and imported it in my `active_admin.js.coffee` by adding the following line:

```
#= require jquery
```

but when I load my custom partial I get the js error.

My rails 5 app is api-only except for active admin which I'm customising so I do not have an application.js to import things in.

Answer (score 1):

Check your application.rb for `config.api_only`. If its set to `true` it removes the asset pipeline. You can also check if `Rails.application.assets` returns nil.
Basically nothing from `/assets` gets compiled or served.

Possible solution:
https://medium.com/alturasoluciones/how-to-set-up-rails-api-app-to-use-activeadmin-79b418df8aad

The issue is that they make the API only and afterwards add everything that is removed through the config back to the app.
Also read the comments in the blogpost for further insight and implications.